# How to test Related Objects in EF Repository using Moq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking

I'am testing my Entity Framework repository but I got some problems when using **Moq - Unit Test** specially when test a method with related objects.

The problem occurs when I try sending mock object [Patient] with some [Bookings] as the data source of a repository method and query it to get a patient with conditional bookings but I'm getting all the bookings even not satisfy the conditions.
My tests working perfectly when querying directed objects with no conditional related ones.

> Test SetUp Method

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var mockDbContext = new Mock<IApplicationDbContext>();

        mockPatient = new Mock<DbSet<Patient>>();
        mockBookings = new Mock<DbSet<Booking>>();

        var patient = new Patient()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Amin",
            Bookings = GetBookings()
        };

        var bookings = GetBookings();

        mockPatient.SetSource(new List<Patient>() { patient });
        mockBookings.SetSource(bookings);

        mockDbContext.SetupGet(c => 
            c.Patients).Returns(mockPatient.Object);
        mockDbContext.SetupGet(c => 
          c.Bookings).Returns(mockBookings.Object);

        _repository = new PatientRepository(mockDbContext.Object);
     }
    private static List<Booking> GetBookings()
    {
        return new List<Booking>() {
                         new Booking() {
                             Patient_Id=1,
                             DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) ,
                             State = new BookingState() {Id=1, Name="Active"}
                             },

                         new Booking() {
                             Patient_Id=1,
                             DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4) ,
                             State = new BookingState() {Id=2, Name="Pending" }
                             }
        };
    }
```

> Tested Method :

```
    [Test] 
    public void GetPatientsWithBookings_GetActiveBookings_ReturnBookings()
    {
        var patients = _repository.GetPatientsWithBookings("Active");
        Assert.That(patients[0].Bookings.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
    }
```

> Method Implementation :

```
    public IList<Patient> GetPatientsWithBookings( string state)
    {

        var Patients = _context.Patients.ToList();

        var PatientsIDs = Patients.Select(p => p.Id);

        _context.Bookings.Where(p => PatientsIDs.Contains(p.Patient_Id) && p.State.Name.Equals(state)).Load();

        return Patients;
    }
```

> SetSource Method :

```
    public static void SetSource<T>(this Mock<DbSet<T>> mockSet, IList<T> source) where T : class
    {
        var data = source.AsQueryable();

        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());

        mockSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => source.Add(s));
    }
```

> Expected : return only one booking which is "Active".
>
> Output : return whole bookings types.

Comment: I wonder ! is no one able to help !!

Comment: that's not something you should be doing. if you want to test your database layer then either use integration testing, as in use your real database or use an in-memory one. either way, you're working with an actual database. don't try to mock Entity Framework, you'll waste your time for nothing